# Simple encryption with encryption key

Tags: c++, encryption

I am doing simple encryption. I have function called encryption(string text, string encryption_key). It should replace text's a's with first letter of encryption_key, b's with second and so on. I am trying to solve this with ASCII values.

I'm not sure if I think this right but I have tried something like this:

```
void encryption(std::string text, std::string encryption_key){
    for(long unsigned int i=0; i< encryption_key.length();i++){
        char letter = encryption_key.at(i);
        for(char j = 'a'; j<='z'; j++){
            if(text.find(j) != std::string::npos){
                text.at(j)= letter;
            }
        }
    std::cout<<"Encrypted text: "<< text<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

I am getting "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' what():  basic_string::at: __n (which is 101) >= this->size() (which is 5) Press  to close this window..."

Is the idea right that I try to go through the encryption key characters first and replace the characters (a-z) in the text?

Comment: Are there both capital and small letters in `text`?

Comment: no only small letters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix to your code is `text.at(text.find(j)) = letter;`

```
void encryption(std::string text, std::string encryption_key){
    for(long unsigned int i=0; i< encryption_key.length();i++){
        char letter = encryption_key.at(i);
        for(char j = 'a'; j<='z'; j++){
            if(text.find(j) != std::string::npos){
                text.at(text.find(j))= letter;
            }
        }
    std::cout<<"Encrypted text: "<< text<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

I belive however, the algorithm is wrong from what you've described.

EDIT:
Without using libraries you can do:

```
void encryption(std::string text, std::string encryption_key)
{
    for (int i=0; i<text.length(); i++)
    {
        for (char ch = 'a'; ch<='z'; ch++)
        {
            if (text[i] == ch)
            {
                text[i] = encryption_key[ch-'a'];
                break;
            }
        }    
    }

    std::cout<<"Encrypted text: "<< text<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now it is running. Need to fix the letter replacement correctly.                  (Enter the encryption key: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
Enter the text to be encrypted: hello
Encrypted text: zyzyz
Press <RETURN> to close this window...)

Comment: Added an algorithm for your reference. Hope it helps.

Comment: Your suggestion without libraries works well with this test: Enter the encryption key: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
Enter the text to be encrypted: thismessageisnotrealyencryptedtoomuch
Encrypted text: thismessageisnotrealyencryptedtoomuch

Comment: but it wont give the right result for this this test:  Enter the encryption key: qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm
Enter the text to be encrypted: quickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog
Encrypted text: jbgmavkgvfngbhbdhlgcmkmgmljmnkgb
***should be***Encrypted text: jxoeawkgvfygbpxdhlgctkzitsqmnrgu

Comment: What is happening in "text[i] = encryption_key[ch-'a'];"? Cause if there is 'a' in text it should be replaced with first character of encryption_key

Comment: First iteration: ‘a’-‘a’ which will become encryption_key[0] second iteration: ‘b’-‘a’ which will become encryption_key[1] and so on...

Comment: okey, yeah I understood it correctly but now counting is going a bit wrong

Comment: Hi, please add a break after replacement, I forgot to do it

Comment: with break encrypted text is only "qqqqqqq" if the encryption_key is "qwerty..."

Comment: Oops, maybe it’s continue not break

Comment: unfortunately not. There is also a warning "comparison of integer expressions of different signedness" for the lines  // for(int i=0; i<text.length();i++) and //if(text[i] 1= std::string::npos)

Comment: sry for the late reply, finally have access to a terminal, break is correct, I've tested encryption key: `qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm` Enter the text to be encrypted: `quickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog` and the result is `jxoeawkgvfygbpxdhlgctkzitsqmnrgu`

Comment: note that break must be enclosed with brackets in the if statement otherwise it'll be treated as two separate statements.

Comment: Yes, that was it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Fix:

```
auto pos = text.find(j);
if(pos != std::string::npos) {
    text[pos] = letter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With using `replace` algorithm, you can simply do this. It will go through the `text` string and replace all occurrences of a particular letter with the corresponding value in the `encryption_key`. Here `encryption_key` contains encrypted values for all small letters.

```
void encryption(std::string text, std::string encryption_key){
    int j = 0;
    for(auto i = 'a'; i <= 'z'; i++) //text has only small letters
    {
        std::replace( text.begin(), text.end(), i, encryption_key.at(j)); 
        j++;
    }
    std::cout <<"Encrypted text: "<< text<<std::endl;   
}
```

See [**`DEMO`**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3jsZmYxugLSqVLFR)

Comment: yep, should work like that. I am trying to do it without an algorithm.